# Should we start enclosing strings consistently using back ticks (`)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am learning ES6. Just realized that using back ticks (`) to enclose string values has many benefits - and I am also sure [it is little slower](https://jsperf.com/es6-string-literals-vs-string-concatenation) compare to simple string concatenation.

However, given the browser optimizations and advancement, is it safe to make it a general practice to enclose all strings using back ticks for consistency sake?

In other words, is it safe to establish it as a best practice to enclose string values with back ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back ticks are for template strings, if there are no variables for interpolation in your string then stick to a single quote.

Comment: I understand. It is also meant for multi line strings. However, would it kill performance if I make it a general practice enclose all strings with back ticks instead of using two different variations to enclose string values. I believe, it could improve code consistency.

Comment: If you are using a build system like webpack, which you should be, then all the ES6 features including template strings are transpiled to ES5 anyway, so it wouldn't matter.

Comment: That’s true - thanks!